# Regular expression to find two strigs after a certain occurence of a string

Tags: c#

I want to remove occurrences of two words following a filter word and also remove the filter word in a string.So for e.g. in the below line:

MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC  VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"

filter is VERSION and i want to remove VERSION = 3 and VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE" from the above line.

So the above line should look like:

MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC

The filter parameters like VERSION will be passed dynamically and also the lines will have different formats.The above is just an example.

Comment: `how i can use regular expressions` -> `Regex.Match(input,pattern).Value` :)

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Ok,will post my solution in a while.

Comment: Since regular expressions depend on the format, you might need to dynamically build the regex as well. Can you spare any constraints on the format?

Answer (score 2):

This simple regex should work:

```
var s = "MY FILE = \"/test/test.txt\" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = \"NOT APPLICABLE\"";
var r = new Regex("(MY FILE.*) VERSION.*(CRC.*)VERSION.*");
var m = r.Match(s);
var output = string.Format("{0} {1}",m.Groups[1],m.Groups[2]);
```

the output is

```
MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC
```

**EDIT**

Following OP's edit of the question, a different solution. Assumptions made:

- a single line string of name=value pairs
- name can have spaces (i.e. MY FILE), but won't be in quotes
- value can have spaces, but must be in quotes ("MY VALUE")

`MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"`

and updated code:

```
var original = "MY FILE = \"/test/test.txt\" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = \"NOT APPLICABLE\"";
var nameToRemove = "VERSION";
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

var s = original;
while(s.Length>0)
{
    var getNameRegex = new Regex("(.*?)=");
    var name = getNameRegex.Match(s).Groups[1].ToString();
    s = s.Substring(name.Length+1);
    Regex getValueRegex;
    if (s.TrimStart().StartsWith("\""))
    {
        getValueRegex =new Regex("(\\s*\".*?\"\\s*)");
    }
    else
    {
        getValueRegex =new Regex("(\\s*.*?)\\s+");
    }
    var value = getValueRegex.Match(s).ToString();
    s = s.Substring(value.Length);

    if (name.Trim() != nameToRemove)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(name).Append("=").Append(value);
    }   
}

Console.WriteLine ("original : {0}",original);
Console.WriteLine ("parsed   : {0}",stringBuilder.ToString());
```

and calling the above with different words to remove produces:

**VERSION**

```
original : MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"
parsed   : MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC
```

**MY FILE**

```
original : MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"
parsed   : VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"
```

**CRC**

```
original : MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"
parsed   : MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"
```

**DUMMY** (non-existent in the string)

```
original : MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"
parsed   : MY FILE = "/test/test.txt" VERSION = 3 CRC = 0x1ECC2C78 XYZ = ABC VERSION = "NOT APPLICABLE"
```

Comment: The filter parameters like VERSION will be passed dynamically and the lines will always have different formats.Looks like a hard coded pattern match string.

Comment: That's not mentioned in your question. Please modify the question and include all additional information/samples. We're not mind readers here.

Comment: I got my own solution without using RegEx.Thanks a lot.Will post my solution in a while.